# The mechanic behind Java Predicates

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I came across this code snippet:

```
List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("red", "green", "yellow");
Predicate<String> test = n ->
{
    System.out.println("Searching…");
    return n.contains("red");
};
colors.stream().filter(c -> c.length() > 3).allMatch(test);
```

The output showed me

```
Searching...
```

And when I take the `.filter(c -> c.length() > 3)` away, it showed me

```
Searching...
Searching...
```

And after some other tests I found out that the last element (yellow) was never tested!

Why is that!?

Could somebody please be so kind and explain the mechanic behind it!?

Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). This just wants to know "does every item match this predicate?". This will go through the stream and evaluate the predicate for each item until it finds one that is false, because once it has that, it can say for certain that not every item matches the predicate.

The docs say

> May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result.

Once it finds an item for which the predicate is false, it does not evaluate any further items.

Comment: Also the `.filter(c -> c.length() > 3)` plays a role in count of elements matched in the example shared. When present it excludes `"red"` from being matched hence only `Searching...`, on the other hand, while the `filter` is removed, there are two `Searching... Searching...`